# Simple sum in Javascript does not works

Tags: javascript

I have started my studies on Javascript and I'm having a little difficult with some simples concepts. It is a simples way to sum two numbers but for some reason it's not work.

```js
 function sum() {
        var tn1 = document.getElementById('tn1')
        var tn2 = document.querySelector('input#n2')
        var n1 = Number(tn1.value)
        var n2 = Number(tn2.value)
        var s = n1 + n2
        document.write(s)
    }
```

```html
<body>
<input type="number" id="tn1"> + 
<input type="number" id="tn2">
<input type="button" value="Sum" onclick="sum()">
</body>
```

I know it's probably a simples mistake but i can't find the answer.

Comment: `#tn2` .......?

Comment: Typo: Its actually `#tn2` not `input#n2`

Answer (score 3):

```
var tn2 = document.querySelector('input#n2')
```

There is no element with an id of `n2`. Change it to `#tn2`.

Comment: I recommend to change it to `document.getElementById('tn2')` instead of using querySelector

Comment: It was so simples. I read the code 1000x times and I did not find it. very tank you.
I read that querySelector is a newer way to set stuff. why shouldn't I use it for everything?

Comment: Because that's simply not necessary here. There's a perfectly good function to get an element by its id, so it's likely faster, more browser-compatible, and more readable.